# Unable to import RRDtool in Python

Tags: python, configuration, rrdtool, rrd

I am trying to import [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) into Python as I want to access an RRD database using Python, but when I am trying to `import rrdtool` I am getting the following error.

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/opt/rrdtool-1.4.5/bin')
>>> import rrdtool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rrdtool
```

My RRDtool is located in `/opt/rrdtool-1.4.5/bin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is solved just by executing the following command.

> sudo apt-get install python-rrd

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that Python modules are located inside a 'bin' folder. And importing files from some configured path requires that the referred path is a proper Python package. It means it *must* contain an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: so what exactly i should do ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [py-rrdtool](http://www.nongnu.org/py-rrdtool/), which you could get directly from the site or your package manager.

Comment: i have created a directory under /opt/rrdtool-1.4.5/lib/ and name of the dir is python2.6/ and inside that i have these files 

__init__.py  Makefile  MANIFEST.in  README.txt  setup.py and now i have set the path as sys.path.append('/opt/rrdtool-1.4.5/lib/python2.6/') but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RRDtool documentation for inspiration (`man rrdpyton`). Something
along the lines of

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/rrdtool/lib/python2.6/site-packages/')
import rrdtool
```

should do the trick.